# Using circles with various radii and colors in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I have a big list that I'd want to plot using 'Listplot.'
I replaced it with

```
list = Table[{x, -10 + Abs@(x^2)}, {x, -3, 3, 0.3}]
```

I wish to have a plot as the below picture

[image]

in which the symbols have been replaced by empty circles with a gradient color change.
Furthermore, the radius of these circles ranges from little to huge.
It is preferable to make these radii a factor of their value. In paint I could present what I mean. I searched a lot on this site but did not find what I was looking for. can anyone reach me to the goal!? Because I must use `ListPlot` and not `Plot` I generated a list at the first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### [`BubbleChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html)

```
list2 = Join[list, List /@ Normalize[Abs @ list[[All, 2]], Total], 2];

bubblechart = BubbleChart[list2, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ChartStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.5]], 
 BubbleSizes -> {.01, .05}]
```

[image]

If desired you can post-process to replace disks with circles and points:

```
bubblechart /. d_Disk :> {Circle @@ d, Point @ d[[1]]}
```

[image]

#### [`PointValuePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointValuePlot.html)

```
list3 = list -> Transpose[{#, #} &@Normalize[Abs@list[[All, 2]], Total]];

PointValuePlot[list3, {1 -> "Color", 2 -> "Size"}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", BubbleSizes -> {.01, .05}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is very good but can they be empty and just the line around the circle be colored?

Comment: I am trying to understand what did you do!!! I get stuck to generate list2 and list3. I cannot understand their roles!!!

Comment: @InzoBabaria, for `BubbleChart` input data should be a list of triples `{{x1,y1,z1}, {x2,y2,z2}...}` where the third coordinate indicates the bubble size (which can also be used for controlling color when the option `ColorFunction` is used) So used the the normalized absolute values of the second column of your `list` to generate z values and append them to the x-y coordinates. For `PointValueChart` I used the input data in the form `list of x-y coordinates -> lists of point-values`  with each point-value being a pair {v1, v2} and used `v1` to code color and `v2` to code bubble size.

Comment: Your explanations are very useful.

Comment: The last changes gets it improved

Answer (score 9):

```
list = Table[{x, -10 + Abs@(x^2)}, {x, -3, 3, 0.3}]
cols1 = ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #] & /@ Subdivide[1, 10]
cols2 = ColorData["Rainbow"][#] & /@ Subdivide[1, 9]
cols = Join[cols1, cols2]
Length /@ {list, cols}
```

You can choose your own color scheme. The lists called `list` and `cols` should be the same length.

```
ListPlot[list
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Epilog -> {Transpose[{cols, Circle[#, Abs@#[[2]]/50] & /@ list}]}
 ]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Or follow this variation using `Thread`:

```
ListPlot[list
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Epilog -> {Thread[{Hue[Abs@#[[2]]], Circle[#, Abs@#[[2]]/40]}] & /@
     list}
 ]
```

[image]